# Error creating kit for Nexus 4 when creating Click target

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I'm trying to autocreate a kit for my Nexus 4.  It is erroring out with a missing dependency.  How do I proceed?

```
 build-essential is already the newest version. 
 apt-utils is already the newest version. 
 apt-utils set to manually installed. 

 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the
 situation: 

 The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 ubuntu-sdk-libs:armhf : 
     Depends: liboxideqt-qmlplugin:armhf but it is not going to be installed

 E : Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

 Command returned 100: schroot -u root -c
 source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf -- /finish.sh 
 Traceback (most recent call last): 

 File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in sys.exit(main())
 File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main return mod.run(args) 
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 266, in run return args.func(parser, args)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 68, in create return chroot.create(args.keep_broken_chroot) 
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/chroot.py", line 592, in create self.full_name, ret_code)) click.chroot.ClickChrootException:
     Failed to create chroot 'click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf' (exit status 100) 
 There was an error creating the click target, cleaning up  

 click target was removed successfully 
 ---Click exited with errors, please check the output---
```

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install -f` help?

Comment: This is occuring during the creation of a Click target for the Ubuntu SDK.  It is an automated script.

Comment: As you can probably see I don't know much about this :p. However, that command might still help. Use it and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this previously answered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678481/there-was-some-errors-creating-kitarmhf), I used the commands at the bottom which appear to create the Click targets themselves outside the Ubuntu SDK.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/tools-development -y

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk-ide ubuntu-sdk-api-tools

$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk-api-15.04-armhf ubuntu-sdk-api-15.04-i386
```

The armhf Click target is now appearing in the Ubuntu SDK options.

Comment: Actually all these packages exist in the ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa so in the official SDK Release PPA. But yes, the static chroot is the solution as the bootstraped schroots are super sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 16.04 I had to add a different ppa

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa -y
```

Comment: According to the tools team at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, after adding the ppa you also have to update, upgrade, and dist-upgrade with apt after adding the ppa. After doing that I was able to create click targets.

Answer (score -1):

It's telling you that, along with `ubuntu-sdk-libs:armhf`, you must install `liboxideqt-qmlplugin:armhf`.

Comment: I'm new to this.  I'm not quite aware what is even being done when creating a kit.  Is this on the host machine or device?

Comment: Form my experience, there is a reason apt cannot install the package.  I ran into this when installing 32-bit packages for compiling wine.

Comment: It's on wherever you're getting the error message.

Comment: I'm getting the error message in the Ubuntu SDK after trying to make a Click Build Target for armhf 15.04.

Comment: It's not as simple as just doing "sudo apt-get install liboxideqt-qmlplugin" on the host machine.  It is already installed.

Comment: lt says you must install `liboxideqt-qmlplugin:armhf`. That `liboxideqt-qmlplugin` (for your native architecture) is installed doesn't matter. Note the difference in the package names. It needs `liboxideqt-qmlplugin:armhf` for the cross-compilation.

Comment: The problem is in the click chroot.  If you want to fix that you need to enter that chroot and try fixing it. But that might not be trivial. I suggest to use the static chroots from the ubuntu-sdk-api-15.04-[armhf|i386]